# what is the meaning Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_zoom' of undefined after i use react leaflet marker cluster?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet, react-leaflet-v3

i getting stuck with using markercluster in react leaflet. i always get error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_zoom' of undefined, i already add markercluster.js, markercluster css but still face the problem.. heres my code

```
<MapContainer
  className={classes.borderRadiusCardPaper}
  center={position}
  zoom={4}
  scrollWheelZoom={true}
  worldCopyJump={true}
>
<TileLayer
  attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">GoogleMaps</a> contributors'
  url="https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=r&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}"
/>
<MarkerClusterGroup>
  {inisiatifDataFull.map((item) => (
    <div key={item.id}>
      <Marker
        icon={customMarkerLoc("images/markerrr.png")}
        position={[
          item.long,
          item.lat,
        ]}
      >
      <Popup>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td style={{
              background:   "#8ab4f8",   
              padding:      "5px",
              borderRadius: "6px",
              fontWeight:   "bold",
              color:        "white",
              }}
            >Provisi
            </td>
            <td>{item.provinsiname}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style={{
              background:   "#8ab4f8",
              padding:      "5px",
              borderRadius: "6px",
              fontWeight:   "bold",
              color:        "white",
            }}
            >Kabupaten / Kota
            </td>
            <td>{item .kabupaten .length }</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
                                <td
                                    style={{
                                        background:
                                            "#8ab4f8",
                                        padding:
                                            "5px",
                                        borderRadius:
                                            "6px",
                                        fontWeight:
                                            "bold",
                                        color: "white",
                                    }}
                                >
                                    Jumlah
                                    Insiatif
                                  </td>
                                <td>
                                    {
                                        item.provinsiname
                                    }
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td
                                    style={{
                                        background:
                                            "#8ab4f8",
                                        padding:
                                            "5px",
                                        borderRadius:
                                            "6px",
                                        fontWeight:
                                            "bold",
                                        color: "white",
                                    }}
                                >
                                    Jumlah
                                    Goal
                                  </td>
                                <td>
                                    {item.sdgs_goal.map(
                                        (
                                            item
                                        ) =>
                                            item
                                                .sdgs_goals
                                                .length
                                    )}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </Popup>
                </Marker>
            </div>
        ))}



                     </MarkerClusterGroup>
</MapContainer>
```

i use react 16.2
react leaflet v3
and then leaflet 1.7.1

if you have a alternative marker cluster library.. let me know about it.. thank you

Comment: Can you share MapContainer code ?

Comment: i already share the MapContainer code, please check it

Comment: I only see the code where you invoke MapContainer. Where is the code that defines it?

Comment: MapContainer is imported from react-leaflet

Comment: I think we're going to need some more detail here, as there's nothing immediately obvious in your code that's wrong.  What versions of react, leaflet, react-leaflet, and react-leaflet-markercluster are you using.  Can you reproduce this error in a codesandbox?  What is the full stack trace of the error?